# Integrated TTL in SPDT-switch

Tags: microcontroller, switches, ttl

Found a switch for a project, and want to make sure I understand it correctly.

This is the switch:
(Mini-Circuits [SWMA-2-50DR+](http://194.75.38.69/pdfs/SWMA-2-50DR+.pdf)).

Now, it has a TTL driver circuit with the inputs +5V, -5V, and TTL IN.
The TTL IN has low threshold 0-0.8V and high threshold 2-5V.

Will it be possible to control the switch with a microcontroller that alternates its output between 0V and 5V, and is directly connected to the TTL IN input? Or is it necessary with some kind of circuit in between?

Comment: The logic levels has maximum currents of 0.2mA (low threshold) and 5mA. I could put a 5kOhm resistor between the output of the MCU and the TTL IN, but wouldn't that drop the voltage on the input?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the purpose of a TTL input.

(That's quite a small surface-mount package ..)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct the RF switch can be controller using MCU.
Make sure to check the MCU logic also any of 3.3V or 5.0V versions.

Logic High:2.0 to 5.0V

Logic Low: 0 to 0.8V